# Get bytes from /dev/urandom within range while keeping fair distribution

Tags: linux, random, range, nasm

I want to generate random numbers in assembly (nasm, linux) and I don't want to use the libc (for didactic reasons), so I'm planning on reading /dev/urandom.

The thing is, I would like them to be in a specific range.

For instance let's say I want a number from 0 to 99.

When I read a byte from /dev/urandom it will come in the range 0x00 to 0xff (255).

One thing I could do is apply a mod 100, which would guarantee the correct range.

But the problem with this approach is that some numbers have more chance to
come out than others.

The number 51 would come out from 3 different results:

```
51  % 100 = 51
151 % 100 = 51
251 % 100 = 51
```

The number 99 would come only from 2 different results:

```
99  % 100 = 99
199 % 100 = 99
(there will be no 299 since the range of a byte ends in 255).
```

The only solution I came up with involves discarting the random number 
when it is in the range 200-255 and reading another one.

Is there a more clever way to read a random byte, and make sure 
it is in a certain range while being "fair"?

What if I'm planning to read lots of bytes within a range?
Is there a way to be fair without discarting lots of urandom reads?

I heard about the getrandom(2) linux syscall, but it's not yet in a stable kernel (3.16.3 as of this time). Is there an alternative?

Comment: First thing that comes into mind is that since you're using `/dev/urandom` which doesn't block, why just read one byte?

Comment: I was planning on reading one byte for each random number, if the upper limit is <=255, since there's no need to read more.

Comment: @diogovk, there is reason to read more if you don't want to throw some of the reads away...

Comment: I'm sorry but its not clear to me exactly what I should do with the extra bytes.

Comment: @diogovk I think what they're suggesting is that you read several bytes in one call to increase the likelihood that *one* of the bytes in the return value will be within your range.

Comment: There's a paper (which right now I'm unable to find right now :) suggesting reading N bytes to reduce entropy waste: eg if you wanted numbers up to 1000 you could read four bytes and get three numbers out of it - the last three **decimal** digits, the middle 3 and the upper 3, up to 1000.0000.000; basically you would be wasting 2 bits out of 32. If anyone remembers about it and can add a link - thank you!

Comment: The paper is "Bit recycling for scaling random number generators" (re-reading my comment I notice only know that I wrote something really stupid - 4.000.000.000, not 1.000.000.000!)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ioreb.
That's a great article. But this is quite hard for me to completely understand given I seem to lack some necessary background.
The beginning of the article has a nice and easy language, and the first example is easy to follow, but after that it becomes more demanding for me to understand.